# What happens when an iframe opens a new window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup

Will it open as a normal new window or will it be bounded by the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a window.open() inside the iFrame, it will open another fresh browser window not bound to the iFrame. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/uVbZb/

Opens in a new window, regardless of being in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test and find out?

Yes, it will open a normal new window.